# Printing Pagination with Header and Footer

Tags: cakephp, printing, pagination

Using CakePHP, I have a view with a table listing all orders. This table sits between the header and the footer. I would like to limit the table to 12 items, and keep the header and footer. If the list is more than 12, I need it do to the following:

Append header just below 'first page' footer, followed by table(with again, max 12 items), followed by the footer. If the 'second page' table has more than 12 items, the same process should happen.

Note: I have reviewed the stack question 'Pagination with header and footer', as well as a few 'printing pagination' questions, but I'm still struggling with how to approach this. I didn't provide any code, because I'm not necessarily looking for an 'answer' but a point in the right direction. If I need to provide more information, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: So instead of Pagination you just want to display the next 12 results lower down on the page in its own table? having trouble understanding what your after

Comment: As described this doesn't have anything to do with pagination. You want to display all rows, with headers a footers injected into the table every 12 rows?

Comment: @AD7six Yes, that makes more sense. I'll do some research on my own for taking that approach. I appreciate the help.